# SDL2 Get the coordinates of a pixel

Tags: sdl-2

I have a window with an image as my user interface and I'm trying to see between what coordinates the buttons that I drew on that image are defined. I need those for the following condition:

```
if (mouseX0>a && mouseX0<b && mouseY0>c && mouseY0<d
  && event.window.windowID == user_interface)
```

I do not know at the moment between which coordinates are the buttons. I found out there is a function that could get the coordinates of a pixel I would click in my window and I could print that then use it in my code. I want to click on each corners of the buttons so I could have the a, b, c, d values.

Answer (score 0):

The information you need is stored in [SDL_MouseButtonEvent](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MouseButtonEvent) event structure (the `x` and `y` values obviously) . Just check the mouse events in your event loop as you click. See [SDL_Event](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Event) for example code on event processing and filtering.

Also if you have a static image for your UI, you just can measure that info in any graphics editor, just lookup coordinates under your cursor, which is basic functionality in most apps.